# Need help debugging Bootstrap/CSS that renders fine everywhere but iPad

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My [site](https://dantrimble.com) renders fine on every browser I’ve tested on both desktop and iPhone. However, on iPad, it cuts off the content at the top, no matter which browser is being used. (Each browser shows a slightly different amount of the content.) Super simple, single page site built with Bootstrap 3.

Would appreciate any pointers about where I went wrong with the code. CSS is not my strong suit; I’m relearning it, so apologies for what I’m sure is a basic question.

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS so that we can try and help

Comment: Are you using fixed-top navbar? If so you must add a `padding-top: 70px` on the `<body>` tag as on its specs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#navbar-fixed-top